# Flex 4 How to create an Encrypted SQLite Database

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, encryption, air

How can I create and use an encrypted SQLite database for an AIR application, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on the following:
http://elromdesign.com/blog/2009/04/16/adobe-air-sqlite-manager-api-for-adobe-air-15-with-password-encryption/